# How do I remove duplicate words from a list in python

Tags: list

I have the following list:
Liste=['hello','hello word','word','red','red apple','apple','king']
and I want to remove the duplicate words that include in other words like 'hello' and 'word','red', and 'apple'
so the ResultsList will be like this:['hello word', 'red apple','king']
i tried a few methods but didn't work for me!
So anyone can help with a simple solution to my problem?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO , _i tried a few methods but didn't work for me!_ , can you please elaborate what you tried and where did you failed? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thank's .for example i used a 'set' method but nothing change in my list : ResultsList = sorted(set(Liste), key=lambda x:Liste.index(x))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myList = ['hello','hello word','word','red','red apple','apple','king']
newList = []

for item in myList:
  unique = True
  current = myList.pop()  

  for string in myList:
    if current in string:
      unique = False

  if unique:
    newList.append(current)  

  myList.insert(0, current)

print(newList)
```

Loop through your list, each iteration pops the last element from the list. Thereafter loop through the remaining elements and evaluate if the string we popped is a substring of any of the other remaining strings.

If not, we consider the string we popped unique and we can append it to an empty list. At the end of each loop iteration insert the string we popped to the beginning of the original list.

set() would work if you were looking to remove exact duplicates and not substrings.

Comment: can you check for this use case
myList = ['hello','hello world red','hello word','word','red','red apple','apple','king']

Comment: Works. Output ['king', 'red apple', 'hello word', 'hello world red'] (Notice that word and world are different)

Comment: Glad to help, If possible please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer so users know it works. See: [Accepting An Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)